# Update data with new data from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I copied data from one sheet to the master sheet
using the macro copy technique. When I review the code it has:

```
Sub UPDATE2()
'
' UPDATE2 Macro
'

'
    Range("B2:B10").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("PAC Summary").Select
    Range("Z13:Z21").Select
    Selection.Insert SHIFT:=xlDown
    Sheets("RTF").Select
    Range("F16").Select
End Sub
```

How do I change this line `Selection.Insert SHIFT:=xlDown` so that the updated value doesn't append as new records when I add a new value.
I just want the value to be updated.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What happens right now? What would you like to happen instead? I don't understand what you mean with "updated value doesn't go down". Your code INSERTS rows and shifts the existing rows down. If you don't want to do that, don't insert, but just paste.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a macro you don't need all the selection stuff. You can get the same by this code:

```
Sheets("HereTheNameOfSourceSheet").Range("B2:B10").Copy Destination:=Sheets("PAC Summary").Range("Z13:Z21")
```

If you are sure that your source sheet is active when starting the macro you can shorten the line:

```
Range("B2:B10").Copy Destination:=Sheets("PAC Summary").Range("Z13:Z21")
```

Comment: I think `RTF` is the source sheet. :)

Comment: you don't even need full target range address and just go `Range("B2:B10").Copy Destination:=Sheets("PAC Summary").Range("Z13")`

Comment: @DisplayName: Yes I know. It was just for the analogy to the original code :-)

Comment: thank you so much @Fratyz , i understand better now, i also found another way to update master sheet with new data from another sheet, but this helps though since im new to excel vba